# Find the value of $\angle BDE$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

> In the figure below, $\angle CAB=\angle ABC=\angle ADB=70^\circ$ and $CD=BE$. Find $\angle BDE$.

[image]

Comment: Can you translate the question in full (especially part ii)?

Comment: The question wants the value of angle bde.that is what part 2 means.in part 1 you can see the given values of other things.u just need whats written in english the othe part is unnecessary

Comment: @Saad Tahmid I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg i did not get u.where is the solution

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Its been edited

Comment: I have tried alot but i don't think its solvable. That's why i posted here.in fact i joined this forum just now

Comment: @SaadTahmid: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) So, tell us about how you "tried alot". As comments are easily overlooked, edit the question to add details.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let $O$ be the center of the circumcircle $\Omega$ of the triangle $BCD$.  Then, $OC=OD=OB$.  Because $$\angle BCD=40^\circ=\angle ABD\,,$$ we conclude that $AB$ is tangent to $\Omega$ at $B$.  Therefore, $OB\perp AB$, so$$\angle CBO=90^\circ-\angle ABC=20^\circ\,.$$
Because
$$\angle CBD=\angle ABC-\angle ABD=70^\circ-40^\circ=30^\circ$$
and
$$\angle COD=2\,\angle CED=60^\circ\,,$$
the triangle $COD$ is equilateral (having $OC=OD$ and $\angle COD=60^\circ$).  Thus, the radius $\Omega$ is $OC=OD=CD=BE$.

In the figure above, all thick line segments have the same length.  As $OB=BE$, the triangle $BOE$ is isosceles and we get $$\angle BOE=\frac{180^\circ-\angle EBO}{2}=\frac{180^\circ-20^\circ}{2}=80^\circ\,.$$
Now, 
$$\angle DOB=2\,\angle DCB=80^\circ=\angle BOE\,.$$
Ergo, $D$, $E$, and $O$ are collinear.  Thus,
$$\begin{align}\angle BDE&=\angle BDO=\angle DBO\\&=\angle CBD+\angle CBO=30^\circ+20^\circ=50^\circ\,.\end{align}$$

Comment: Alternate segment theorem. Smart

Comment: And for a shorter statement, since you deduced $\Delta COD$ is equilateral you could've just said that $ADC$ is a straight line and hence use $180-70-60$. Good answer though.

Comment: How can you confirm it to be tangent.i did not understand that part

Comment: @Plato  No, I can't.  I don't know yet that $D$, $E$, and $O$ are collinear.  So, I don't know yet if $\angle CDE=\angle CDO$.  That is why I had to go through the trouble establishing collinearity of $D$, $E$, and $O$.

Comment: @SaadTahmid  As Plato said, it's the Alternate Segment Theorem (see https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/).

Comment: Yeah by the way. Neat trick.

Comment: @Plato  Yes, if we have established that $D$, $E$, and $O$ are collinear, then you can get $\angle BDE=\angle BDO=180^\circ -70^\circ-60^\circ$.

Comment: Thank u guys.its my first post.so now i have some idea about this forum

Comment: Hey @Batominovski i just thought why would you need the alternate string theorem.we already have the 70 degree.so adding a 20 degree would make AB a tangent anyways and we could find the line BO which has the centre O

Comment: @SaadTahmid  What?  I know that $\angle CBO=20^\circ$ because I proved that $AB$ is tangent to $\Omega$, not the other way around.  How do you know without knowing tangency of $AB$ to $\Omega$ that a line making $20^\circ$ to $BC$ will pass through $O$?  And the name of the theorem is not the Alternate *String* Theorem.  It is the Alternate ***Segment*** Theorem.

Comment: Im not saying ur wrong.im just saying even if you dont know that theorem.we could just suppose a 20 degree

Comment: @SaadTahmid So, if you draw the $20^\circ$-line, how do you know $O$ will be on that line (without knowing first that $AB$ is tangent to the circle)?  I could do the same at $C$.  Drawing a line $CP$ that makes an angle $50^\circ$ at $C$ so that this line is perpendicular to $AC$.   You will immediately see that the line $BC$ is not a tangent to $\Omega$, and the line $CP$ does not pass through $O$.  Having $O$ on the perpendicular to $AB$ at $B$ is important to the problem.

Comment: Im sorry man .i thought B to be acontact point